# Change text of a textbox when other textbox text is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two input type = text. The text of the textbox is populated from a custom date picker module. I want to change the content of second text box when the text of first text box is changed.

```
<input type = "text" id = "one"> 
<br>
<input type = "text" id = "two">
<br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Javascript

```
function myFunction()
{
    document.getElementById('two').value = 'hello';
}
```

Here I have just simulated the change of textbox 'two' on button click but actually it is changed by some other methods.
I want to change the text of textbox 'one' when value of textbox 'two' is changed.
Events like onchange and keyup wont work as the text is explicitly changed.
Checking the value of both text boxes for equality at interval of 1 sec is also not an option for me.

Plain Javascript or jQuery is fine.

Comment: Why don't you just change the value of `#one` within `myFunction` also?

Comment: What you're probably looking for is the `change()` method in JQuery (http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: Why doesn't `keyup` work? What events are you working with in your script? Can you post a (simple, [short, self-contained, correct/compilable](http://sscce.org/)) [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Because I am not entering the text by typing, the test is set by some external event. The answer by semsem is exactly what I want. Thanks all for suggessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is built on two javascript functions as follows:

```
function myFunction()
{
    ob = document.getElementById('two')
        ob.value = 'hello';
    ob.focus();
    ob.blur();

}
function sync(){
   document.getElementById('one').value = document.getElementById('two').value 
}
```

here is the HTML:

```
<input type = "text" id = "one"> 
<br>
<input type = "text" id = "two" onblur="sync()">
<br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>​
```

The following is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/saidbakr/hD6Sx/

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using jQuery:

Live view:
http://jsbin.com/aqiyaz/1/

Code:
http://jsbin.com/aqiyaz/1/edit